# write a python function that takes a list and one column of a dataframe and adds a new column based on that list

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

## I oversimplified this greatly - the actual column will contain up to 500 characters and the substring list will have 60 values, anywhere from 10-80 characters

dataframe is more complicated than this, list would contain 60 values, DF would have 11,000 rows, but here is what I am trying to do

I have a dataframe like so, and a list

```
my_list = ['alabama 500', 'beta 15', 'carthouse', 'd320 blend']

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['left side alabama 500 on the right side carthouse', '1st entry is at beta 15', 'this one takes a mix of d320 blend and beta 15']})


    col1
0   left side alabama 500 on the right side carthouse
1   1st entry is at beta 15
2   this one takes a mix of d320 blend and beta 15
```

I am attempting to write a function that would return this, keep the first column intact and return the substring in a new column with the original column intact

```
df['col2'] 
    col1                                                  col2
0   left side alabama 500 on the right side carthouse     alabama 500
1   left side alabama 500 on the right side carthouse     carthouse
2   1st entry is at beta 15                               beta 15
3   this one takes a mix of d320 blend and beta 15        beta 15
4   this one takes a mix of d320 blend and beta 15        d320 blend
```

here's what I have tried

```
def add_new_col(data, col_name, my_list):
    #function looks at the column col_name in a dataframe data, if the substring exists, it adds a new
    #column with only that substring, keeping multiples
    
    for i in my_list:
        if data[col_name].str.contains(i):
            data['col2'] = i
        else:
            continue
    return data
```

running the function in the notebook

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
add_new_col(df, 'col1', my_list)
```

returns this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

based on some other answers I also tried this

```
def add_new_col(data, col_name, my_list):
    #function looks at the column col_name in a dataframe data, if the substring exists, it adds a new
    #column with only that substring, keeping multiples
    
    for i in my_list:
        if data[data[col_name].str.contains(i)]:
            data['col2'] = i
        else:
            continue
    return data
```

which gave the same error code

Comment: Don't understand the logic for col2.  For instance, rows 0 & 1 in col1 are both 'acd', but in col2 we get 'a' for row 0 and 'c' for row 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `explode` method:

```py
df2 = df.assign(col2=lambda f: f.col1.apply(list)).explode("col2")
print(df2)
```

```
  col1 col2
0  acd    a
0  acd    c
0  acd    d
1    a    a
2   db    d
2   db    b
```

If you want to get rid of the index just add:
`df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: the actual column 1 will contain up to 500 characters, this was an oversimplification, column 2 is a list of 60 items, all strings up to 80 characters long

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split` and `concat`:

```
import numpy as np
s = df['col1'].str.split('',expand=True).replace('',np.nan).stack()\
              .reset_index(1,drop=True).to_frame('col2')

df1 = pd.concat([df,s],1)

  col1 col2
0  acd    a
0  acd    c
0  acd    d
1    a    a
2   db    d
2   db    b
```