# I have a list of 60 complicated items, i have a dataframe with a text column that I would like to extract all the items from the list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I tried to ask this here and I oversimplified it too greatly

I have a list of 60 unique text items, varying in length and what they contain, I have a text column in a dataframe that has that information plus extra information, I would like to add a new column preserving the original and adding rows when duplicates from the list are encountered in the dataframe

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
my_list = ['alabama 500', 'beta 15', 'carthouse', 'd320 blend', 'royal blue lugnuts']
# in actuality this list contains 60 different items, anywhere from the color red, to a sentence with 80 characters

# this is an example of how each row can sometimes contain multiple items from the list, but not always
# it is important to capture the multiples, and that all of the original rows are maintained, but to also isolate the items from the original list
# all of the data are strings
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['left side alabama 500 on the right side carthouse near the royal blue lugnuts', '1st entry is at beta 15', 'this one takes a mix of d320 blend and beta 15']})

In [1]: df

Out [1]: 

    col1
0   left side alabama 500 on the right side carthouse near the royal blue lugnuts
1   1st entry is at beta 15
2   this one takes a mix of d320 blend and beta 15
```

goal:

```
    col1                                                                            col2
0   left side alabama 500 on the right side carthouse near the royal blue lugnuts   alabama 500
0   left side alabama 500 on the right side carthouse near the royal blue lugnuts   carthouse
0   left side alabama 500 on the right side carthouse near the royal blue lugnuts   royal blue lugnuts
1   1st entry takes beta 15                                                         beta 15
2   this one takes a mix of d320 blend and south takes beta 15                      d320 blend 
3   this one takes a mix of d320 blend and south takes beta 15                      beta 15
```

I tried to write a function here, a few different ways, it does not appear to be as simple as a string extract

[write a python function that takes a list and one column of a dataframe and adds a new column based on that list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65186158/write-a-python-function-that-takes-a-list-and-one-column-of-a-dataframe-and-adds)

there is an answer here that is very close,

[Extract string from a dataframe comparing to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41954822/extract-string-from-a-dataframe-comparing-to-a-list)

but so far I don't see how it takes care of duplicates, I tried changing expand to True, also looked at extractall but it doesn't seem to have the same behavior

tried this:

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.extract("(" + "|".join(my_list) +")")
#changed expand to true and false with no change in behavior

    col1                                                                            col2
0   left side alabama 500 on the right side carthouse near the royal blue lugnuts   alabama 500
1   1st entry is at beta 15                                                         beta 15
2   this one takes a mix of d320 blend and beta 15                                  d320 blend
```

trying extractall

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.extractall("(" + "|".join(my_list) +")")
#gives this error
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extractall` returns a new dataframe with multiindex, first level index shows the row number in the original dataframe.

So, you cannot directly append the result of `extractall` to the original `df`. You need to `merge` or something to combine the result to the original `df`.

```
df_ext = df['col1'].str.extractall("(" + "|".join(my_list) +")")
>>> df_ext = df['col1'].str.extractall("(" + "|".join(my_list) +")")
>>> df_ext
                          0
  match
0 0             alabama 500
  1               carthouse
  2      royal blue lugnuts
1 0                 beta 15
2 0              d320 blend
  1                 beta 15

>>> df_ext.merge(df, left_on=df_ext.index.get_level_values(0), right_on=df.index)
   key_0                   0                                               col1
0      0         alabama 500  left side alabama 500 on the right side cartho...
1      0           carthouse  left side alabama 500 on the right side cartho...
2      0  royal blue lugnuts  left side alabama 500 on the right side cartho...
3      1             beta 15                            1st entry is at beta 15
4      2          d320 blend     this one takes a mix of d320 blend and beta 15
5      2             beta 15     this one takes a mix of d320 blend and beta 15
```

This is not that great and as you can see, you still need to clean extra columns.

=====================================================

Alternatively with `pandas >= 0.25.0`, you can use `findall` and `explode`. This is probably simpler to read.

`findall` will return Series with matching strings as in a list. Then `explode` can explode the list into rows.

```
>>> df['ext'] = df.col1.str.findall(f'({"|".join(my_list)})')
>>> df
                                                col1                                           ext
0  left side alabama 500 on the right side cartho...  [alabama 500, carthouse, royal blue lugnuts]
1                            1st entry is at beta 15                                     [beta 15]
2     this one takes a mix of d320 blend and beta 15                         [d320 blend, beta 15]

>>> df = df.explode('ext')
>>> df
                                                col1                 ext
0  left side alabama 500 on the right side cartho...         alabama 500
0  left side alabama 500 on the right side cartho...           carthouse
0  left side alabama 500 on the right side cartho...  royal blue lugnuts
1                            1st entry is at beta 15             beta 15
2     this one takes a mix of d320 blend and beta 15          d320 blend
2     this one takes a mix of d320 blend and beta 15             beta 15
```

I believe there are more ways to achieve this but does either of these satisfy your question?

Comment: thank you so much, this had some weird behavior on the large dataset that I was able to fix with df['ext'] = df['ext'].str[0], it had extracted the data as a tuple. I was trying to use a simpler example, but the findall and explode was exactly what I needed